# Can I call a function from the base class which return bool from derived class

Tags: c++11, inheritance

I have the following base class:

```
class node_layer_manager_t : public layer_manager_t
{
protected:
    //Devices
    trx_t        trx;
private:
    std::vector<string>               trx_dump_labels;

public:
    node_layer_manager_t( xml::node_t& params ); 
    ~node_layer_manager_t();

    virtual bool    set_profile(void) override;    
}
```

I created the following derived class:

```
class node_layer_manager_with_rad_t : public node_layer_manager_t
{
protected:
    //Devices
    radio_t radio;

public:
    node_layer_manager_with_rad_t(xml::node_t& params );
    ~node_layer_manager_with_rad_t();

    virtual bool    set_profile(void) override;

    virtual void radio_monitoring_job_function(void);

    intervalues_t<double>   radio_tmp;
    ushort          duration_seconds_for_radio_monitoring;
};
```

I want it so that the set profile will execute the set_profile of the base class and in addition some other action.

Can I just write it this way?

```
bool node_layer_manager_with_rad_t::set_profile(void)
{
    bool success;
    node_layer_manager_t::set_profile();
    try
    {
        string_t profile_tag = "logs/trx_dump/node:"+get_id();
        dev_tx = profile->get_decendant(profile_tag.c_str());
        cout<<"sarit id= "<< get_id()<<endl;
        success = true;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout<<"sarit  profile error: "<<endl;
        success = false;
    }
    return success;  //**
}
```

**Or should I reurn the follwing:

```
return (success && node_layer_manager_t::set_profile());
```

Comment: Is this a question about C++ or about your particular design? If the former, you only *should* write a program that doesn't break language rules. Both of your variants look OK in this regard. If the latter, no one could possibly have any idea without understanding the design in full. Tentatively the second variant looks more promising (printing inside a setter looks dubious though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>At first, you haven't declared success anywhere (so actually, this is not a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the code should not compile as is).</s>

Still I get it - and tThe answer is: it depends on what you actually want to do...

Do you want to call the super class first or after the sub class code? Your example implies the former, your alternative the latter. Do you want to abort if the super class function fails or still execute your code?

Your inital example calls the super class function, ignores the result and does its own stuff afterwards.

This calls the super class function first and continues only on success:

```
bool success = node_layer_manager_t::set_profile();
if(success)
{
    try { /*...*/ } // <- no need to set success to true, it is already
    catch(...) { /*...*/ success = false; }
}
```

This executes both, but combines the result:

```
bool success = node_layer_manager_t::set_profile();
try { /*...*/ } // <- do not modify success, must remain false if super class failed!
catch(...) { /*...*/ success = false; }
```

Your alternative hints to executing the sub class code first and only call the super class function, if nothing went wrong.

Any of these approaches might be appropriate, none of them might be. You have to get a clear image of what your requirements are - and then implement the code such that your needs are satisfied...

Comment: is it ok to declare both of the set_profile (of the 2 classes) with override right?

Comment: See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override): yes, it is OK (provided that `layer_manager_t` has such a virtual function, too!).

Answer (score 1):

If you *have to* call parent `set_profile` regardless what you have to do in derived class, you should adopt design which take care about this constraint.

Typically, you should mark based class `set_porfile` as `final` and manage call of a dedicated derived class method inside based class:

```
class node_layer_manager_t : public layer_manager_t
{
protected: 
    ....
    // set_profile actions of derived class
    // proposed a default without side effect implementation if
    // derived class doesn't need to overload this.
    virtual bool set_profile_child() { return true; };
private:
    ....
public:
    .....
    // Manage here call of derived
    virtual bool set_profile() override final
    {
        // actions before derived specific actions
        ....
        // Call specific derived class actions
        bool success = set_profile_child();

        // actions after derived specific actions
        if (success)
        {
            //do based class action
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

and in child:

```
class node_layer_manager_with_rad_t : public node_layer_manager_t
{
protected:
    ....

public:

    virtual bool    set_profile_child() override;
};

// Manage only there own action, regardless of needs of based class
bool node_layer_manager_with_rad_t::set_profile(void)
{
    try
    {
        // Do what you're in charge, and only what you're in charge!
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout<<"sarit  profile error: "<<endl;
        success = false;
    }
    return success;  //**
}
```

With this kind of design, each class do only what it have to manage, and only its. Derived class doesn't have to deal with needs of based class.

If you want to offer to your derived class ability to decided if code is executed before or after generic behavior, you can replace or add to `set_profile_child()` two methods: `bool pre_set_profile()` and `bool post_set_profile()`

Comment: This is a good approach (+1), but not the holy grail either. You dictate when the sub class' code is executed, so something like `class Sub1::do() { doSomething(); Super::do(); } class Sub2::do() { Super::do(); doSomethingDifferent(); }` gets impossible...

Comment: @Aconcagua if you need this behavior, you can replace `bool set_profile_child()` by `bool pre_set_profile()` and `bool post_set_profile()` (or have this 3 methods)

Comment: Hum, it may be a bad answer because I don't really think about that point, but first answer that comes to mind is: if based class allows derived class to manage exception, based class has to offer correct interface => add a `virtual void handle_set_profile_expection(TheException &e)`

Comment: (Oh, deleted my comments already, answered myself alike...). My version was `if(!handle(TheException& e)) throw;`, so had bool as result. But I think we get at where the problem is: any time you did not foresee a behaviour a derived class needs already in your base class, you have to modify both. There are absolutely situations where it is worth to pay that price (that's why I upvoted - I am still aware of the pre-condition that the base class code *must* be executed), but others when it is simpler or more efficient (consider high performance code) just to let override the outer function.

Comment: This is similar to what I wrote in my own answer: everything depends on the requirements you impose (or get imposed) on the result...

Comment: @Aconcagua I agree with you when you say that depends on the requirements. But for maintainability and future expansion, IMHO fixing interface, mandatory behavior and role of each class is really important. Also I'm not sure that this solution impacts significantly performance (must do experiments). And for hight performance code, we prefer not to use virtual class. In conclusion, both answer are correct, it depends just of you requirements ;)